# How to clear my timers using clearInterval() in my Trivia Game?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been working on this Trivia Game for awhile now and I can't seem to get these timers down, i've exhausted all my resources finding the solution to clear my timers.

Here is the html:

```html
<div class="game-wrapper"></div>
<div id="container">
  <h1>Trivia Game</h1>
  <div class="card">
    <div id="time">Time Left: <span id="timer"></span></div>
    <div id="question"></div>
    <div id="answers">
      <button id="optionA"></button>
      <button id="optionB"></button>
      <button id="optionC"></button>
      <button id="optionD"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the js:

```js
var time     = 20;
var timeLeft = $('#timer');
var interval;

function timerRun() {
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    time--;
    $(timeLeft).text(time);
    console.log(time);
    if (time === 0) {
      unanswered++;
      $('#unanswered').text(unanswered);
      resetTime();
      renderQuestion();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function stopTimers() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}

function resetTime() {
  stopTimers();
  time = 20;
  $(timeLeft).text(time);
}

function startAnswers() {
  $(optionA).on('click', function () {
    console.log('this is the correct button');
    console.log('this button is being clicked A');
    correct++;
    $('#correct').text(correct);
    $('#optionA').addClass('correct-button');
    $('#optionA').removeClass('correct-button');
    renderQuestion();
    resetTime();
    timerRun();
  });
  $(optionB).on('click', function () {
    console.log('wrong button');
    console.log('this button is being clicked B');
    incorrect++;
    $('#incorrect').text(incorrect);
    $('#optionB').addClass('incorrect-button');
    $('#optionB').removeClass('incorrect-button');
    renderQuestion();
    resetTime();
    timerRun();
  });
  $(optionC).on('click', function () {
    console.log('wrong button 2');
    console.log('this button is being clicked C');
    incorrect++;
    $('#incorrect').text(incorrect);
    $('#optionC').addClass('incorrect-button');
    $('#optionC').removeClass('incorrect-button');
    renderQuestion();
    resetTime();
    timerRun();
  });
  $(optionD).on('click', function () {
    console.log('wrong button 3');
    console.log('this button is being clicked D');
    incorrect++;
    $('#incorrect').text(incorrect);
    $('#optionD').addClass('incorrect-button');
    $('#optionD').removeClass('incorrect-button');
    renderQuestion();
    resetTime();
    timerRun();
  });
}
```

Up above I've tried to clear my intervals with a function, but each time i click a button the timer is still

Comment: Remove `var` inside `timerRun`. That shadows the global `interval`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this line:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () { ...
```

Remove the "var" to work, because how its set you are using a local variable, not the global scope that clearInterval() uses.